# What is the proper modern way to use RecyclerView with ContentResolver to retrieve all media on the phone?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Basically I have an old `RecyclerView` with an `Adapter` that uses the `Cursor` directly. As far as I understand it, this isn't ideal because any time I do a `Cursor` operation like `moveToNext()` or similar, it performs disk IO, right? and that is happening on the UI thread.

So what is the recommended way for me to implement an infinite (basically keep loading items as the user scrolls) `RecyclerView` with `ContentResolver` to display videos or images stored on the phone?

Thanks.

Comment: [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) ?

Comment: Yeah that looks like the right way to do it. Are there any examples out there that use `ContentResolver`?

Comment: Think this might be the way to do it http://eng.moldedbits.com/android/2018/05/02/android-paged-lists.html

Comment: @bwt since you suggested the paging library, if you want to add that as an answer I will select it as the correct answer.

Comment: that's nice of you, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Jetpack's [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) could be a good solution. As you found yourself it is possible to [use it with a `ContentProvider`](http://eng.moldedbits.com/android/2018/05/02/android-paged-lists.html)